# Parsing JSON without the table name

Tags: android, json, parsing, hashmap

I'm trying to parse a database using JSON.
But, I don't know how to parse a JSON file to get the name and value of the table **without the need to declare the table's name preloaded**

```
 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

           JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           String id = item.getString(TAG_email);
           String name = item.getString(TAG_name);
           String address = item.getString(TAG_id);

           HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

           hashMap.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
           hashMap.put(TAG_NAME, name);
           hashMap.put(TAG_ID, id);

           mArrayList.add(hashMap);
       }
```

Which means, if I have to get the email address, I have to tell the code to parse 'email', but is it possible to load all the table's name (email, name, id) by itself and parse the value?

Comment: Can you post the json structure?

Comment: @Kilian {
     "test": [
       { "email": "test@test.com"
         "name": "John"
         "id": "jtst"
       }
     ]
    } here you go

Comment: Pretty sure you should be able to use [JSONObject.keys()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) to retrieve the keys, then use the keys to fetch the values.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
JsonArrayRequest getJsonData = new JsonArrayRequest("<your_url>,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Users mList = new Users();

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONArray answers = obj.getJSONArray("emails");

                        long count = answers.length();
                        if(count > 0){
                            //setter methods
                        }

                        mList.setIDL(obj.getString("_id"));
                        list.add(mList);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("JSONError", e.toString());
                    }

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //your listview findViewById().....
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error in fetchinf data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: we have to input "emails" in order to parse the passage. i want to parse without giving the table's name